# Why does this div's background show through at the top when it should be completely filled by its contents?

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` containing another `div` containing an `input`. The outer `div` gets its height from the inner `div`, which gets its height from the `input`. There is no padding or margin on the divs. I've removed the border from the input. Why is the outer `div`'s red background showing through for one pixel at the top? And why does it get *worse* when the `input` has `padding: 0`? (Use the checkbox to try it.)

I've isolated it to the `input`'s `border: none` style (removing that gets rid of the red bar), but I'd like to understand *why* it has that effect (on both Chrome and Firefox).

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("input[type=text]").classList.toggle("zero-padding", this.checked);
});
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
    /* divs don't have padding or margin by default, but I did try this just in case
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    */
}
.inner {
    /* divs don't have padding or margin by default, but I did try this just in case
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    */
}
.inner input {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
}
.zero-padding {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"><input type="text"></div></div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Add <code>padding: 0</code> to the <code>input</code>
  </label>
</div>
```

My result on Chrome v58 on Linux:

[image: Result on Chrome]

My result on Firefox v53 on Linux:

[image: Result on Firefox]

Comment: The red shows through at the *bottom* for me on Firefox. It's likely because the input is an inline element - padding has strange effects on the sizing of input elements, but the background showing through definitely has to do with it being inline in both browsers.

Comment: try adding `.inner input { box-sizing: border-box; }`.

Comment: @BoltClock: Oh dear, really? You don't see what I see on Firefox (added picture above)? Scary.

Comment: @biziclop: Good point, I tend to forget it's not inherited by default. (I normally use Paul Irish's reset for that, but the project I'm on doesn't...) Doesn't change it, though.

Comment: The plain `div` and the input text have different font-size by default. div font-size: 16px, input font-size: 11px. Also see line-heights. See your browser's inspector! So either fix font-sizes, or apply `display: block` on the input.

Comment: @biziclop: Thanks! Oh, trust me, I've been inspecting like mad. What I didn't get, though, was that the `div.inner` would allocate a full line of height rather than just take the height of the `input`. But that's exactly it, on my system, the `div.inner` ends up being 20px but the `input` is only 17, thanks to differing default `font-size`s. Got there in the end thanks to [blecaf's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43790065/157247).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those divs default properties e.g font sizes, line-height. I solved this by setting line-height of "outer" div to 0;

```js
document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector("input[type=text]").classList.toggle("zero-padding", this.checked);
});
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outer {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 5em;
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: red;
    line-height: 0;
    /* divs don't have padding or margin by default, but I did try this just in case
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    */
    
}
.inner {
    /* divs don't have padding or margin by default, but I did try this just in case
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    */
}
.inner input {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    background: white;
}
.zero-padding {
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer"><div class="inner"><input type="text"></div></div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox"> Add <code>padding: 0</code> to the <code>input</code>
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: *Doh*! Of course. It's font-size. The `div.inner`'s font-size is 16px (on mycopies of Chrome and Firefox), but the `input`'s font-size is 13.33px (Chrome) or 12px (Firefox).

Comment: What I didn't appreciate was that the `div.inner` would allocate a full line of height, rather than just taking the height of its content. But since `input` is `inline-block` by default, of course it does...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `input` field has `display: inline-block` by default.

If you set

```
display: block;
padding: 0;
```

on the input, it fixes it.

Why? No idea actually... :(

Comment: Thanks. But it's the *why* that's bothering me... :-)